# Получение родительского элемента, а после нужного дочернего

Tags: javascript, jquery

Код html

```
<div class='answer'>
    <a name="answer_5"></a>
    <div class='quastion_title'>
        <h3>
            Вопрос
        </h3>
        <small>
            <a href="#top" class='to_top'>Наверх&#8593;</a>
        </small>
    </div>
    <p>Ответ</p>
</div>
```

Страница — ссылки и якоря. При клике на ссылку получаю имя якоря.

```
url = window.location;
p = url.toString().split('#');
anchor = p[1]; //Имя якоря. Тут это answer_5
```

И теперь нужно как-то добавить класс к `<h3>`. Я попробовал получить родителя и уже от него плясать, но ничего не выходит. Как быть?

```
if (anchor) {
    p = jQuery("a[name='"+anchor+"']").parent();
    //???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, зря ставили кавычки при поиске элемента по его имени. Во-вторых, после того, как нашли этот элемент и его родителя, ищете в его родителе нужный вам `h3` и после этого добавляете ему нужный вам класс.

```js
var anchor = "answer_5"
jQuery("a[name=" + anchor + "]").parent().find("h3").addClass(anchor);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='answer'>
  <a name="answer_5"></a>
  <div class='quastion_title'>
    <h3>
      Вопрос
    </h3>
    <small>
                <a href="#top" class='to_top'>Наверх&#8593;</a>
            </small>
  </div>
  <p>Ответ</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (anchor) {
    jQuery("a[name='"+anchor+"']").siblings("div").children("h3").addClass("myClass");
}
```

siblings - Осуществляет поиск элементов, являющихся соседними для выбранных элементов
children - Находит дочерние элементы